# How to match old password while changing password in spring security?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, change-password

I am using spring security in java based web application. I need to create a change password screen where user will have to type in old password to confirm.

I need to check if the old password typed in by the user matches his old password in the db.

How do i do it in the spring security.

Below is my spring security java config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager(AccessDecisionVoterImpl accessDecisionVoter) {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> accessDecisionVoters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter<?>>();
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new WebExpressionVoter());
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
        accessDecisionVoters.add(accessDecisionVoter);
        UnanimousBased accessDecisionManager = new UnanimousBased(accessDecisionVoters);
        return accessDecisionManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new PasswordEncoder();
        passwordEncoder.setStringDigester(stringDigester());
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public PooledStringDigester stringDigester() {
        PooledStringDigester psd = new PooledStringDigester();

        psd.setPoolSize(2);
        psd.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
        psd.setIterations(1000);
        psd.setSaltSizeBytes(16);
        psd.setSaltGenerator(randomSaltGenerator());

        return psd;
    }

    @Bean
    public RandomSaltGenerator randomSaltGenerator() {
        RandomSaltGenerator randomSaltGenerator = new RandomSaltGenerator();
        return randomSaltGenerator;
    }
```

Also, when new user is created i set his password as below.

```
user.setPassword(passwordUtils.encryptUserPassword(user.getPassword()));


@Component("passwordUtil")
public class PasswordUtils {

    @Autowired
    private PooledStringDigester _stringDigester;

    public String encryptUserPassword(String originalPassword) {
        String encryptedPassword = _stringDigester.digest(originalPassword);
        return encryptedPassword;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the Password stored in the db by using Username/Email/User Id and finally write a function in `PasswordUtils` which makes use of `PooledStringDigester.matches`

```
public boolean isPasswordsMatch(String newPassword, String passwordFromDb) {
    return _stringDigester.matches(newPassword, passwordFromDb);
}
```